# Can one node publish only a single static transform?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, tf-static, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My code is like this where I am publishing 3 static transforms from three static publishers-

```
  #include <ros/ros.h>
  #include<fiducial_msgs/FiducialTransformArray.h>
  #include <tf2_ros/static_transform_broadcaster.h>
  #include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>
  bool arr[3]={0,0,0};
  geometry_msgs::TransformStamped static_transformStamped[3];

  bool all_true(bool *arr)
  {
  for(int i=0:i<3;i++)
  if(arr[i]==0)return false;
  return true;
  }
  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "calibrate");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster static_broadcaster[3];
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/camera/fiducial_transforms", 10,transform_callback1); 
  //fill a static_transform_stamped message
  ros::Subscriber sub2 = n.subscribe("/camera1/fiducial_transforms", 10,transform_callback2);
  ros::Subscriber sub3 = n.subscribe("/camera2/fiducial_transforms", 10,transform_callback3);

  //few callbacks made 
  while(!all_true(arr))
  {
  ros::spinOnce();
  usleep(1000000);
  }

  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
  static_broadcaster[i].sendTransform(static_transformStamped[i]);

  ros::spin();
  return 0;
  }
```

But on doing

```
rostopic echo /tf_static
```

I get only one(the last one) static transform. So what is happening here? Do I need to create a new node for publishing a different static transform?

**EDIT:**
Adding the callbacks definition-

```
void transform_callback1(const fiducial_msgs::FiducialTransformArray msg)
    {
       static int i=0,j=0;
       if(msg.transforms.size()>0)
        {

           if(j==0)
            {
                 j+=1;
                 static_transformStamped[i].header.stamp = msg.header.stamp;//ros::Time::now();
                 static_transformStamped[i].child_frame_id = "aruco";
                 static_transformStamped[i].header.frame_id = msg.header.frame_id;//"/camera_color_frame";
                 static_transformStamped[i].transform = msg.transforms[0].transform;
                 arr[i]=1;
            }
             ROS_INFO("camera fiducial detected");
        }
    }

void transform_callback2(const fiducial_msgs::FiducialTransformArray msg)
    {
       static int i=1,j=0;
       if(msg.transforms.size()>0)
        {

           if(j==0)
            {
                 j+=1;
                 static_transformStamped[i].header.stamp = msg.header.stamp;//ros::Time::now();
                 static_transformStamped[i].child_frame_id = "aruco1";
                 static_transformStamped[i].header.frame_id = msg.header.frame_id;//"/camera_color_frame";
                 static_transformStamped[i].transform = msg.transforms[0].transform;
                 arr[i]=1;
            }


            ROS_INFO("camera 1 fiducial detected");
        }
    }

void transform_callback3(const fiducial_msgs::FiducialTransformArray msg)
    {
       static int i=2,j=0;
       if(msg.transforms.size()>0)
        {

           if(j==0)
            {
                 j+=1;
                 static_transformStamped[i].header.stamp = msg.header.stamp;//ros::Time::now();
                 static_transformStamped[i].child_frame_id = "aruco2";
                 static_transformStamped[i].header.frame_id = msg.header.frame_id;//"/camera_color_frame";
                 static_transformStamped[i].transform = msg.transforms[0].transform;
                 arr[i]=1;
            }
                 ROS_INFO("camera 2 fiducial detected");
        }
    }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320947/can-one-node-publish-only-a-single-static-transform?/) by [Harsh2308](https://answers.ros.org/users/31217/harsh2308/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2019-04-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-04-12**:
Can you edit to add the construction of static transform stamped message please? I sense that the problem is with the header of the transforms.

**Comment by [Harsh2308](https://answers.ros.org/users/31217/harsh2308/) on 2019-04-12**:
I just added it. I don't know if you will be notified, so commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is with the `ros::spin()` call at the end of the file. Until `ros::spin()` is called, the subscriber callbacks will not be executed. You can read up on it [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning).

I suggest you change the callbacks similar to this.

```
oid transform_callback1(const fiducial_msgs::FiducialTransformArray msg)
{
   static int i=0,j=0;
   if(msg.transforms.size()>0)
    {

       if(j==0)
        {
             j+=1;
             static_transformStamped[i].header.stamp = msg.header.stamp;//ros::Time::now();
             static_transformStamped[i].child_frame_id = "aruco";
             static_transformStamped[i].header.frame_id = msg.header.frame_id;//"/camera_color_frame";
             static_transformStamped[i].transform = msg.transforms[0].transform;
             arr[i]=1; // I'm not sure what this does. Not declared anywhere in your code snippet
            static_broadcaster[i].sendTransform(static_transformStamped[i]);
        }
         ROS_INFO("camera fiducial detected");
    }
}
```

And then change your main to

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include<fiducial_msgs/FiducialTransformArray.h>
#include <tf2_ros/static_transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>
static tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster static_broadcaster[3];
geometry_msgs::TransformStamped static_transformStamped[3];
int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
          ros::init(argc, argv, "calibrate");
          ros::NodeHandle n;
          tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster static_broadcaster[3];
          ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/camera/fiducial_transforms", 10,transform_callback1); ///fill a         static_transform_stamped message
          ros::Subscriber sub2 = n.subscribe("/camera1/fiducial_transforms", 10,transform_callback2);
          ros::Subscriber sub3 = n.subscribe("/camera2/fiducial_transforms", 10,transform_callback3);


          ros::spin();
          return 0;
    }
```

Furthermore, you don't need an array of `static_broadcaster`. One broadcaster can send multiple static transformation messages.

**EDIT**
I have tested this code. It works.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include<fiducial_msgs/FiducialTransformArray.h>
#include <tf2_ros/static_transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>

void transform_callback1(const fiducial_msgs::FiducialTransformArray);
void transform_callback2(const fiducial_msgs::FiducialTransformArray);
void transform_callback3(const fiducial_msgs::FiducialTransformArray);

static int a = 0;
static int b = 0;
static int c = 0;

geometry_msgs::TransformStamped static_transformStamped[3];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "calibrate");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster static_broadcaster;
  ros::Subscriber sub1 = n.subscribe("/camera1/fiducial_transforms", 10,transform_callback1); ///fill a     static_transform_stamped message
  ros::Subscriber sub2 = n.subscribe("/camera2/fiducial_transforms", 10,transform_callback2);
  ros::Subscriber sub3 = n.subscribe("/camera3/fiducial_transforms", 10,transform_callback3);

  while( a == 0 || b == 0 || c == 0) {
      ros::spinOnce();
  }

  for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    static_broadcaster.sendTransform(static_transformStamped[i]);
  }

  ROS_INFO(" All TFs published");

  return 0;
}

void transform_callback1(const fiducial_msgs::FiducialTransformArray msg)
    {
       if(msg.transforms.size()>0 && a == 0)
        {
            a = 1;
        
            static_transformStamped[0].header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
            static_transformStamped[0].child_frame_id = "aruco1";
            static_transformStamped[0].header.frame_id = "/camera_color_frame";
            static_transformStamped[0].transform = msg.transforms[0].transform;

            ROS_INFO("camera1 fiducial detected");
        }
    }

void transform_callback2(const fiducial_msgs::FiducialTransformArray msg)
    {
       if(msg.transforms.size()>0 && b == 0)
        {
            b = 1;
        
            static_transformStamped[1].header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
            static_transformStamped[1].child_frame_id = "aruco2";
            static_transformStamped[1].header.frame_id = "/camera_color_frame";
            static_transformStamped[1].transform = msg.transforms[0].transform;

            ROS_INFO("camera2 fiducial detected");
        }
    }

void transform_callback3(const fiducial_msgs::FiducialTransformArray msg)
    {
       if(msg.transforms.size()>0 && c == 0)
        {
            c = 1;
        
            static_transformStamped[2].header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
            static_transformStamped[2].child_frame_id = "aruco3";
            static_transformStamped[2].header.frame_id = "/camera_color_frame";
            static_transformStamped[2].transform = msg.transforms[0].transform;
                    
            ROS_INFO("camera3 fiducial detected");
        }
    }
```

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2019-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Harsh2308](https://answers.ros.org/users/31217/harsh2308/) on 2019-04-14**:
Thanks for the reply.
I changed to multiple broadcasters assuming single broadcaster can only send one static transform.
I don't understand why will I want to send static transforms on every iteration in the spin loop. The purpose of static transform is to register that transform once and for all on the tf tree.
If you look at the demo [static_broadcaster](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20static%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29) code, you will see that the node publishes the transform once only.

Sending transforms on every callback fails the concept of static transform.
Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

(
Also what I actually want to do is:
[

1. I have 3 cameras , all of them see a fiducial[aruco marker] and I get 3 cameratoaruco transforms.
2. I compute transformation b/w camera1&camera2 and camera1&camera3.
3. I send these as static transforms.
   ]
   )

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-04-14**:
You are correct in that you only need to broadcast a static transformation once. If you look at the callback, the variable `j` makes sure that the transform is broadcasted only once.

**Comment by [Harsh2308](https://answers.ros.org/users/31217/harsh2308/) on 2019-04-14**:
Yes you are right. So what is the difference doing it before and now? In your solution, again the line `static_transformStamped[i].transform = msg.transforms[0].transform;` is executed only once (for all i s).

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-04-14**:
The `ros::spin()` needs to be called within your program for callbacks to be executed. In your code, the static transformations are broadcasted **before** `ros::spin()` is called. So the transform stamped message array is not set with your transformation data. That only happens once the subscriber callbacks are executed. You can read up on [ros::spin()](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning) and how it works [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning).

**Comment by [Harsh2308](https://answers.ros.org/users/31217/harsh2308/) on 2019-04-14**:
Ah, my bad. I actually posted a truncated code as it seemed super redundant. Anyway, as you can see now I was ensuring few callbacks are made before I move to sending static transform. I have edited the code where the problem was occurring.

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-04-14**:
I have edited the answer with a fully working solution. [Github repo](https://github.com/jseanm1/ros_answers)

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-04-14**:
And please take a couple of minutes to reformat your question. When you edited, the code formatting was lost and now it's hard to read.

**Comment by [Harsh2308](https://answers.ros.org/users/31217/harsh2308/) on 2019-04-14**:
Hi. When node dies tf_static(if called later when transforms were published) shows no output. I added ros::spin() at the end that ensures node doesn't die and that way tf_static shows the three transforms. Your solution works, Thanks. I still don't find how is your code different and what is wrong with my code above in the question? Marking this as correct.

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-04-14**:
Hi, yes, you need to add the `ros::spin()` after broadcasting to continue receiving the `tf`.
As for why this is different from your code, the code in the edited question is not different in its approach and should work the same way. In your previous version, you had the problem of not calling `ros::spinOnce()` which I assumed to be the problem. Isn't the current version of your code working?

**Comment by [Harsh2308](https://answers.ros.org/users/31217/harsh2308/) on 2019-04-14**:
It doesn't. Weird but changing the array of static broadcasters to one static broadcaster made my code work.